# Is there any way to write custom or native queries in Java JPA (DocumentDbRepository) while firing a query to azure-cosmosdb?

Tags: java, sql, spring-data, azure-cosmosdb

Connected to azure-cosmosdb and able to fire default queries like `findAll()` and `findById(String Id)`. But I can't write a native query using `@Query` annotation as the code is not considering it. Always considering the name of the function in respository class/interface. I need a way to fire a custom or native query to azure-cosmos db. ?!

Tried with @Query annotation. But not working.

1. ```java
   List<MonitoringSessions> findBySessionID(@Param("sessionID") String sessionID);
   ```
2. ```java
   @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM MonitoringSessions M WHERE M.sessionID like :sessionID")
   List<MonitoringSessions> findSessions(@Param("sessionID") String sessionID);
   ```

`findBySessionID()` is working as expected. `findSessions()` is not working. Below root error came while running the code.

Caused by: `org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findSessions found for type MonitoringSessions`

Comment: You are using Spring Data Cosmosdb, not Spring Data JPA, right?
Spring Data Cosmosdb doesn't seem to have a `Query` annotation and you can't simply use an annotation from a different Spring Data Module.

Comment: HI @JensSchauder. Then, is there any way to write custom queries to get data from azure cosmos db using Spring Data Cosmosdb ?

Comment: I would expect the normal mechanism to work, but I never used SD CosmosDB so I can't tell for sure. Just give it a try: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response. I got what I exactly wanted from the below link. Credit goes to Author of the link page.

https://cosmosdb.github.io/labs/java/technical_deep_dive/03-querying_the_database_using_sql.html

public class Program {

```
 private final ExecutorService executorService;
 private final Scheduler scheduler;
 private AsyncDocumentClient client;

 private final String databaseName = "UniversityDatabase";
 private final String collectionId = "StudentCollection";

 private int numberOfDocuments;

 public Program() {
     // public constructor
     executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
     scheduler = Schedulers.from(executorService);
     client = new AsyncDocumentClient.Builder().withServiceEndpoint("uri")
             .withMasterKeyOrResourceToken("key")
             .withConnectionPolicy(ConnectionPolicy.GetDefault()).withConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.Eventual)
             .build();

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, JSONException {
     FeedOptions options = new FeedOptions();
     // as this is a multi collection enable cross partition query
     options.setEnableCrossPartitionQuery(true);
     // note that setMaxItemCount sets the number of items to return in a single page
     // result
     options.setMaxItemCount(5);
     String sql = "SELECT TOP 5 s.studentAlias FROM coll s WHERE s.enrollmentYear = 2018 ORDER BY s.studentAlias";
     Program p = new Program();
     Observable<FeedResponse<Document>> documentQueryObservable = p.client
                     .queryDocuments("dbs/" + p.databaseName + "/colls/" + p.collectionId, sql, options);
     // observable to an iterator
     Iterator<FeedResponse<Document>> it = documentQueryObservable.toBlocking().getIterator();

     while (it.hasNext()) {
             FeedResponse<Document> page = it.next();
             List<Document> results = page.getResults();
             // here we iterate over all the items in the page result
             for (Object doc : results) {
                     System.out.println(doc);
             }
     }

 }
```

}